# Effect of Internal ADC capacitor in Microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, current, analog, adc

The input pin mentioned in the below image is the input pin of the microcontroller.

It explains that the internal capacitor of A/D peripheral of MCU should be very much less than the external capacitor placed outside the input pin of the MCU. But I am not able to understand it. Can you please explain it in simple terms on why it should be like that?

[image]

Comment: Similar to blood testing to find out if someone is healthy. If you take too much, then you affect the health of the person you are trying to test defeating the purpose. You do not want your measurement to affect the thing you are measuring which it will do if your measurement takes too much, and a large cap takes more charge to reach the same voltage than a smaller one.

Comment: Can you tell me which is wine sample and which is barrel?

Comment: I changed it to something you are more familiar with. But internal cap is the test vial of blood (or sampling cup of wine), external cap is the person (or wine barrel).

Answer (score 2):

External impedance should be low enough to charge the Csh via Rs full enough in the given sampling time so that you don't get too much error in the result.

If the external impedance is too high, or the sampling time too fast, the Csh does not fully charge to the actual voltage you are sampling and you get lower voltage as result.

And I say impedance, because the measured voltage might come through an external circuit which may be resistive such as a voltage divider, or there might be capacitor like in the picture.

Imagine measuring a 6V battery via a resistor divider, and the divider divides the voltage into half for measurement. If the resistors are both 1 kohms, the circuit has output impedance of 500 ohms and that is usually low enough to charge the capacitor quickly. But 1 kohm divider draws 3mA from battery and depletes it quickly, so same divider could be made with 1 megaohm resistors to consume less current. But with 500 kohm output impedance, it can't charge the sampling capacitance to the measured voltage, so there will be error. Sometimes it can be possible to make sampling time longer, but simple MCUs don't allow this. So a capacitor can be set to the IO pin so that it is large enough that the capacitor voltage does not drop when the sampling capacitor is connected.

Then the problem is that since resistive divider is high impedance, the external cap must be allowed to charge between taking samples, if multiple samples are taken quickly then the high impedance divider can't keep the capacitor voltage as the samplig capacitor draws charges from it.

Comment: Is \$C_{SH}\$ always discharged between samples?

Comment: @devnull Usually not, you have to consider worst case scenario. Configure sampling time to be long enough so that sample capacitor is charged to less than 1 LSB equivalent voltage. The effect when “previous” voltage distorts results is known as a *crosstalk*

Comment: @MarkoGulin Thanks, I see. Than the sampled voltage could also be higher than the ideal if the input voltage is decreasing. In other words, the error caused by this problem could have both signs, depending if the input voltage is rising or decreasing.

Comment: Exactly, that is why you have to calculate the appropriate sample window duration